# Image-picker by rvera - How to choose which picture is selected?

Tags: jquery, plugins, picker

I use the plugin jquery image-picker (http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/).

My question is : How to choose which picture is selected ?

For exemple I want to automatically select the second image, how can I do that ?

And for a case with multiple selection ?

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  $("select").imagepicker();
 });
```

```
<select class="image-picker show-html" data-limit="2" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/220/200" value="1">Cute Kitten 1</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/180/200" value="2">Cute Kitten 2</option>
  <option data-img-src="http://placekitten.com/130/200" value="3">Cute Kitten 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Add your relevant parts of code to the question.

Comment: OK, but I use the basic code found on the site http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in the [documentation](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/), you could set selected option/s directly to your `select` element, and then sync changes to the existant `ImagePicker` plugin, like this example:

```
$(function() {
    // initial configuration of the plugin
    $("select").imagepicker();

    // somehow change the selected items directly on your select html element
    $("select").val('2');

    // re-sync the plugin
    $("select").data('picker').sync_picker_with_select();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to complete the below answer and for anyone having problems implementing it:

As you can see in the [documentation](http://rvera.github.io/image-picker/), if you do some heavy changes to the 'select' element like adding or removing options you will need to reinitialize the picker.

So after re-sync the plugin you need to reinitilize the picker:

```
// re-sync the plugin
$("select").data('picker').sync_picker_with_select();

// you need to reinitilize the picker
$("select").imagepicker();
```

Comment: Good tip, but in this case the OP is not adding nor removing options so this may not be necessary.